# Custom checkout button in checkout.liquid

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, liquid

I am looking to create my own checkout button in checkout.liquid, we currently have a form checkout process but are running into and issue with getting our submit button to complete an order. We do not want to use the shopify standard checkout since this is a specialized store and everything is $0. Shipping and billing is done outside of shopify.

Here is our current layout for our form.

````
  
  #textHead {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  #configHead{
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .textarea {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: -10px;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  
  .textarea:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 6px 25px 2px rgba(10,10,120,0.15);
    transform: translateZ(-15px);
  }
  
    .strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: black;
}

.strike > span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #0F4B97;
}

.strike > span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike > span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600');
.check {
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  left: calc(50% + 40px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.containerOuter {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.entry {
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
}
.entry:nth-child(2) {
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}
.entry:nth-child(4) {
  left: 8px;
  top: 58px;
}
.entry:nth-child(6) {
  left: 8px;
  top: 108px;
}
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #545556;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: border-color 300ms;
  width: 20px;
}
.entry-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.overlay {
  background: #fff;
  mask: url(#holes);
  -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  height: 80px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background 300ms;
  width: 40px;
}

.highlight {
  background: #4D98EF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  left: 14px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  transition: transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.2);
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  width: 12px;
}
  
.hidden:nth-child(1):checked ~ .highlight {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.hidden:nth-child(3):checked ~ .highlight {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.hidden:nth-child(5):checked ~ .highlight {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
.hidden:nth-child(1):checked + .entry .circle {
  border-color: #4D98EF;
}
.hidden:nth-child(3):checked + .entry .circle {
  border-color: #4D98EF;
}
.hidden:nth-child(5):checked + .entry .circle {
  border-color: #4D98EF;
}
.check:checked ~ .containerOuter .overlay {
  background: #ecf0f4;
}
  
</style>
<button type="submit" name="checkout" class="Cart__Checkout Button Button--primary Button--full">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</button>
<form action="ecom@epcusa.com" method="get">
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="strike">
      <span>LAB SERVICES</span>
      </div>
    <div id="textHead">Would you like to request lab services from our technology center?</div>
<div class="containerOuter">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" id="input1" name="inputs">
    <label class="entry" for="input1"><div class="circle"></div><div class="entry-label">No</div></label>
    <input type="radio" class="hidden" id="input2" name="inputs" checked="checked">
    <label class="entry" for="input2"><div class="circle"></div><div class="entry-label">Yes</div></label>
    <div class="highlight"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 40 140">
  <defs>
    <mask id="holes">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="140" fill="white" />
      <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="20" fill="black"/>
      <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="70" fill="black"/>
      <circle r="12" cx="20" cy="120" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
    <div id="box" class="config">
      <p id="textHead">Lab Configuration Instructions</p>
    <textarea class="textarea" name="config-instructions" cols="75" rows="5">Combine with order #[Y/N]:
Engineer Email:
Requester Email:
PM Email:
</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="strike">
      <span>SHIPPING</span>
      </div>
  <div>
        <p id="textHead">Ship To MAC:Address</p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="textarea" name="shipping-search" placeholder="MAC:Address" />
    </p>
    <p id="textHead">Custom Address</p>
    <p>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="shipping-search" placeholder="Custom Adress" cols="75" rows="5"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p id="textHead">Shipping Instructions</p>
    <!-- <p id="textSub">Provide any specific shipping requirements for your order.</p> -->
    <p>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="ship-instructions" cols="75" rows="4" placeholder="Example: Forklift driver, proof of insurance required, etc"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p id="textHead">Shipping Method</p>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ship-method" class="textarea">
            <select name="shipping-method" id="ship-method" width="50px">
    <option value="UPS Ground">UPS Ground</option>
    <option value="Fedex Ground">Fedex Ground</option>
    </select>
</label>
</p>
    <p id="textHead">Requested Arrival Date</p>
    <p>
        <!-- <sub>Your order's request date may be based on pre-defined working days and service level agreements related to this store</sub> -->
    </p>
    <input type="date" class="textarea" name="arrival" />
    <p>
        <b>Ship To Contact</b> <!-- (Add API call for contact lookup here if can't integrate it into ship to address - Contact Email / Phone #) -->
        <br /> <sub>Main point of contact for the delivery of your order.</sub>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="search" class="textarea" name="shipping-contact" placeholder="Search Contact" />
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="strike">
      <span>BILLING</span>
      </div>
    <label for="billing"> 
        <b>PO Number</b>
        <br /> 
    </label> 
    <sub>Point of reference for your order.</sub>
    <p>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="po-number" cols="25" rows="1"></textarea>
    </p>
  <div class="strike">
      <span>ORDER INFORMATION</span>
      </div>
    <label for="order-info">
         <b>Ordered By Contact</b>
         <br /> 
        </label> 
        <sub>This contact will receive a confirmation email and order status notifications depending on store access and preferences.</sub>
    <p>
{{ customer.name }} | {{ customer.email }}    
    </p>
    <label for="additional-email"> 
        <b>Additional Confirmation Email Recipients</b>
        <br /> 
    </label> 
    <sub>Add additional email recipients here</sub>
    <p>
        <textarea class="textarea" name="add-email" cols="75" rows="1" placeholder="Seperate with a &quot;,&quot; for multiple addresses"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="reference-number"> 
            <b>Customer Reference Number</b>
            <br /> 
            <sub>Add any additional order identiying reference numbers</sub> 
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <textarea class="textarea" name="reference-number" cols="25" rows="1"></textarea>
    </p>
  <div class="strike">
      <span>COMPLETE CHECKOUT</span>
      </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input1").click(function(){
    $("#box").slideUp("slow");
  });
    $("#input2").click(function(){
    $("#box").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
        </script>

<html>
   
<head>
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
      
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                var x = $("form").serializeArray();
                $.each(x, function(i, field) {
                    $("#output").append(field.name + ":"
                            + field.value + " ");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
   
<body> 
  <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
   
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
   
</html>```
````